# ion-nav-back-button skips one immediate back page in ionic1

Tags: ionic-framework

When I click the ionic navigation back button, app skip the immediate back page and redirected to the first page (ie. When click back from page5, it skip page4 and redirected to page3).

I also tried a manual back by writing a function but the result was same.
How can I resolve this?Please help...

## My code

### 1.View

```
<div class="bar bar-header nav_header">
<button class="button icon ion-arrow-left-b button-clear btn-sm nav_headeritems" ng-click="backstate()">Go Back</button>
<h1 class="title nav_headeritems">Profile</h1>
</div>
```

### 2.Controller

```
$scope.backstate =function(){

$ionicHistory.goBack(-1);
//alert("back");
}
```

Comment: Does it work without -1 when you call goBack() ? Also, can you give us the code which navigate to this current screen (screen 4 to 5 in your example)

Comment: Yes it works with or without that -1. The actual problem is that backstate function executed twice when it called.
why does the function get called multiple times?

Comment: It directly goes to the first screen, or go through the second which redirects to the first ? Show us more code if you can